# Linkedin Application has OAuth User Token and OAuth User Secret, Do they Expire?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

We have 4 fields in Linkedin on creating a application.

API Key:
Secret Key:
OAuth User Token:
OAuth User Secret:

Need to confirm if OAuth user Token and OAuth User Secret expire after 60 days

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the user tokens expire in 60 days. Here is how to refresh them

[LinkedIn Refresh Access Token](http://developer.linkedin.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-refreshing-access-token)