# OAuth token shown in LinkedIn application details - expiry time?

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

The Application Details of a LinkedIn application include a section "OAuth Keys" which lists a consumer key and secret, and also a OAuth 1.0a user token and secret. Does this OAuth 1.0a user token expire? If so, what is the expiry time? I gather it used to be 60 days[1] Is this still the case?

[1] [Linkedin Application has OAuth User Token and OAuth User Secret, Do they Expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17593081/linkedin-application-has-oauth-user-token-and-oauth-user-secret-do-they-expire)

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 1.0a and OAuth 2.0 access tokens from LinkedIn have a 60 day expiry.